# Javascript Settimeout problem

Tags: javascript

In my application i am using asp.net3.5,ajax.dll.

I am calling all functionalities using ajax from javascript.

Sometimes i need to get the condition results from server side, only then i will be able to pass to next condition.

for the above case, javascript passes to next condition before executing the first condition.

So i added the following code to make it work,

`setTimeOut("finddefaultvideo()",1000);`.

Can anyone please help me to get rid of this issue?

One thing i understood that,it won't wait for the time until server returns the value.

any idea to overcome the above one?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood you correctly but this might be the solution you are looking for (however it is using jquery)

```
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

the alert message is shown as soon as your ajax request was success full and the server sent response data.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout is not reliable for this unless you do some kind of recursive polling technique. You need to invoke `finddefaultvideo` after the ajax callback has returned. You could place `finddefaultvideo()` inside of your ajax callback, the one that's fired `onreadystatechange` and where the readyState is 4 and 'complete'.

```
ajaxCallback: function(html) {
    if ( something ) {
       executeRestOfCode();
    }
}

function executeRestOfCode() {
    // your code that needs to be invoked after the ajax callback
}
```